# "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found." When importing pygpu

Tags: anaconda, keras, theano, conda

I installed theano, keras, pygpu, and libgpuarray via conda install, and I get this error. I'm attempting to run a convolutional network on my GPU. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.  I had originally installed the latest pygpu 0.6.4.   When I installed pygpu 0.6.2 then I still got a lot of error messages, but at least it used the GPU!

Run the following command to downgrade:

```
conda install theano pygpu=0.6.2
```

I hope that helps!

Robert